# Where does System.Runtime.CompilerService.Dynamic attribute comes from and are we supposed to use it?

Tags: c#, .net

Today I was looking at some code of [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) and since I like to explore the code I noticed following thing.

While navigating in VS2017 I went to `NancyModule` I saw the code from the metadata the following:

```
public virtual void Delete(string path, [Dynamic(new[] { false, true, false })] Func action, Func condition = null, string name = null);`
```

Now I don't know what this attribute does so I immediately went to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287751(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Parameters
>
> *transformFlags:*
>   Type: System.Boolean[]
>   Specifies, **in a prefix traversal of a type's construction**, which Object occurrences are meant to be treated as a dynamically dispatched type.
>
> Remarks
>
> For instance, if C is a generic type with two type parameters, a use of the constructed type C might be intended to treat the first type argument dynamically and the second typically, in which case the **appropriate attribute specification should use a transformFlags value of { false, true, false }.**

After that I realized that in Nancy's  [code](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/NancyModule.cs) there is no such attribute applied so I thought myself "Okay, so maybe the compiler adds it." However, after decompiling this assembly with dnSpy, ilSpy I don't see such attribute at all.

So bottom line questions are:

- Is this attribute intended for usage by users of .NET framework or it is only the compiler applying it (given the fact its namespace)?
- What does those flags mean in its constructor? I am not sure I understand what is *prefix traversal of a type's construction*.

Comment: When using ILSpy, take a look at how things are decompiled when you switch to IL, rather than C#. You should see the attribute appear. `dynamic` is just `object` under the covers, with attributes to indicate that the actual type is `dynamic` and not just a regular `object`. Likewise, `Func<dynamic, object>` is really `Func<object, object>` with the attribute to specify the first argument is `dynamic`. The decompiler VS uses just isn't clever enough to turn this back into "canonical" C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dynamic` keyword in C# does not have a dedicated type in the metadata and at runtime, it is simply *object*.  When you add a reference to the assembly then you like to see it back as *dynamic*.  So does the C# compiler, necessary so it can auto-generate the binder code.  The [Dynamic] attribute ensures that happens.

A decompiler would do the same thing so it doesn't have to show you this attribute either.  Whatever tool you used to browse the metadata wasn't that smooth about it and revealed the detail.

The C# compiler emits the attribute automatically.  Nothing you have to do yourself.

Comment: Nice! I was secretly hoping you answer my question, this is all nice, but still do you know these transform flags and their meaning since msdn doesnt say much :(

Comment: It is *supposed* to not matter to C# programmers so MSDN just doesn't have much need to say anything about it.  They have to document because it is public, but do prefer to document it as minimally as possible, just in case they ever decide to change it.  It does matter to the kind of programmers that write .NET compilers, but they have to understand the DLR binder first.  Steep learning curve.

Comment: actually I forgot to ask you do you know what does “prefix traversal of a type’s contruction” means?

Comment: I don't exactly know, it is gobbledygook.  "type construction" refers to the type parameters for a generic type.  I don't know what the first one does.